# Memory Error while trying to read csv on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

When I am running the following code, I am getting the error:

```
import os
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO # Python 2.x
else:
    from io import StringIO # Python 3.x

# get your credentials from environment variables
aws_id = 'XX'
aws_secret = 'YY'

client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_id,
        aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret)

bucket_name = 'arpbhatnagar'

object_key = 'application_train.csv'
csv_obj = client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key)
body = csv_obj['Body']
csv_string = body.read().decode('utf-8')

train = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string))
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error: MemoryError                               Traceback (most
>   recent call last)  in ()
>        21 csv_obj = client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key)
>        22 body = csv_obj['Body']
>   ---> 23 csv_string = body.read().decode('utf-8')
>        24 
>        25 train = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string),low_memory=True,engine='python')
>
> /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc in decode(input, errors)
>        14 
>        15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):
>   ---> 16     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
>        17 
>        18 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
>
> MemoryError:

Comment: How big is `application_train.csv`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running out of memory when downloading or ingesting `application_train.csv`. To solve that problem, you can download the file to your disk first, and then provide the filename to Pandas:

```
tmp_filename = "/tmp/application_train.csv"
client.download_file(bucket_name, object_key, tmp_filename)
training_set = pd.read_csv(tmp_filename)
```